# Is there heat transfer through radiation in a drinking flask with styrofoam insulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, convection

Suppose we have a drinking flask with styrofoam between outer and inner walls. The heat can be transferred through styrofoam by conduction. Is the heat transferred by radiation as well?

My lecturer says "no":

> There is no radiative transfer: material is opaque. Radiation is absorbed on surfaces.

Is he right?

Answer (score 0):

He is right, but for a different reason:

at the temperatures typical of drink containers, radiative heat transfer (which scales as ~(T)^4) is very small compared to convection and conduction. This means that to keep a drink cool, you need to suppress convection and conduction, which is what the styrofoam does, and not worry about radiation.

Comment: Ok, so radiative transfer *still occurs* through styrofoam? We just ignore it because it is small compared to heat transfer through conduction?

Comment: @Chemomechanics, yes! That's all I want to know: is there any heat transfer through radiation with styrofoam?

Comment: We can't know unless we know the thickness of the styrofoam and the [penetration depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_depth) of the styrofoam around the predominant wavelength of interest. Perhaps the styrofoam is so thin that it is effectively transparent; perhaps not.

Comment: @Chemomechanics, let's say 1cm of styrofoam and the radiation is in infrared?

Comment: That thickness is likely sufficient to be considered completely opaque in the IR, but I can't find a reference to support this claim.

Comment: If something is opaque to one wavelength of IR, it will simply absorb that and re-emit at a different wavelength.

Comment: It will not be radiated through the styrofoam, but to add to @HiddenBabel ‘s comment, heat will radiate from the hot side to the styrofoam where some will be reflected and some will be absorbed.  The heat absorbed will partially conduct through the styrofoam to the other side, where it will be emitted at a lower temperature.